# Mysql select where two stored dates are two or more days apart

Tags: mysql, datediff

This is probably a simple question but I am a MYSQL newbie and only every use simple selects, inserts and update queries.

I have a database of bookings that contains a `from date` and a `to date`. I would like to run an SQL query that will return all rows where the `to date` is 2 or more days after the `from date` (so it only returns bookings that are 2 days long or more.

I have been playing with DATEDIFF and manged to do this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(`to`,`from`) AS length FROM `bookings`;
```

which returned the correct data:

```
length
4
3
2
2
1
```

How can I then use the output to select the entire row based on the length being 2 or more?

Comment: Come on. If we have to answer this one then there really is no hope left for humanity.

Comment: @Strawberry It is nearly Christmas... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `bookings` WHERE DATEDIFF(`to`,`from`) >= 2;
```

?

Comment: Yup. That got it after I added ticks.